# How to use a variable in a regular expression to replace-all?

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to replace multiple occurrences of 'text1' with 'text2', in '#area', here is my code that works just fine:

```
var replaced = $('#area').html().replace(/text1/g, 'text2');
$('#area').html(replaced);
```

But imagine the 'text1' is a value of an input box, so:

```
var search = $('#blah').val();
var replaced = $('#area').html().replace(/search/g, 'text2'); <--- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
$('#area').html(replaced);
```

As you can see in the second line, I did `/search/g` but it's not working, how should I put the `search` value there?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 has nothing to do with my question, please always read the question first :-)

Comment: Read it more carefully :-). (Hint: There's something to do with the constructor) Also the first result on Google already answered your question: https://www.google.com/search?q=js+regex+with+variable

Comment: Make sure that titles *accurately* describe the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

If `search` is a variable, you need to use a dynamic regex([RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp))

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (s) {
        return value.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

//then later in your method
var search = $('#blah').val();
var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(search), 'gi');
var replaced = $('#area').html().replace(regex, 'text2');
$('#area').html(replaced);
```

Comment: what if `text2` is also a variable?

Comment: @behz4d `$('#area').html().replace(regex, replacer);`

Comment: Props for providing a solution that uses escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Or even simpler:

```
var search = $('#blah').val();
var re = new RegExp(search, 'g');

str = str.replace(re, '');
```

Comment: how is it simpler than the below one

Comment: @nickrubin - Yours is exactly the same as Arun's answer, except you do not escape special characters first.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
Replace String:
<input type="text" id="blah" />
<br/>Text:
<input type="text" id="area" />
<br/>
<button onclick="myReplace()">Replace</button>
```

JS:

```
function myReplace() {
    var search = $('#blah').val();
    var regex = new RegExp(search, 'g');
    var replaced = $('#area').val().replace(regex, 'text2'); 
    $('#area').val(replaced);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ljaepu1s/)